# MongoDB using mongoose driver: how to query on a subset of document's array property?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of voter registration data. These take the form:

```
voter = {
  name: "Some name",
  registrationDate: "2015-10-21T15:41:36+00:00",
  votingHistory: ["2015-10-21T15:41:36+00:00", "2015-7-21T15:41:36+00:00"]
}
```

I need to be able to detect the size of a subset of the votingHistory array. For example, this is one of the queries I tried:

```
voters.find({
  votingHistory : { $all : {$size : { $gt : 8 }}, { $gt : "2015-7-21T15:41:36+00:00" }}
})
```

The intention of this query is to find all voters with at least 8 recorded votes after 2015-7-21. Is there a way with mongoose to query on the size of subsets of array properties?

For example, with the following three entries:

```
{
  name: "name1",
  VotingHistory: ["2015-10-21T15:41:36+00:00", "2013-7-21T15:41:36+00:00"]
}, 
{
  name: "name2",
  VotingHistory: ["2015-10-21T15:41:36+00:00", "2011-7-21T15:41:36+00:00"]
}, 
{
  name: "name3",
  VotingHistory: ["2013-10-21T15:41:36+00:00", "2011-7-21T15:41:36+00:00", "2009-10-21T15:41:36+00:00", "2010-7-21T15:41:36+00:00"]
}
```

I'd like to find where 2 or more elements in the VotingHistory array represent a date on or after 2013-7-21. Which is only name 1 in this example.

Answer (score 1):

For effective querying, I would suggest modifying your mongoose schema by changing the string literals that represent the dates to actual dates.

You can modify this at schema definition first, for example

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var voterSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    registrationDate: Date,
    votingHistory: [Date]
});

var Voter = mongoose.model("Voter", voterSchema, "voters" );
```

Once that's done, you would need to modify the existing collection by using the **[`Bulk Operations API`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** to leverage your updates. For any given mongoose model there exists a .collection accessor that essentially accesses the "collection object" from the underlying "node native driver" on which mongoose is implemented itself. With this you can do the following updates on documents where the `registrationDate` field is a string

```
mongoose.connection.on("open", function(err, conn) { 

    var bulk = Voter.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    var counter = 0;

    Voter.find({"registrationDate": {"$type": 2} }, function(err, docs) {
        async.each(docs, function(doc, callback) {
            var regDate = new Date(doc.registrationDate),
                history = doc.votingHistory.map(function (dt){
                    return new Date(dt);
                });
            bulk.find({"_id": doc._id}).updateOne({
                "$set": {
                    registrationDate: regDate,
                    votingHistory: history
                }
            });
            counter++;

            if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
                bulk.execute(function(err,result) {             
                    bulk = Voter.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
                });
            } 
            else {
                callback();
            }
        },

        // When everything's done
        function(err) {
            if ( counter % 1000 != 0 ) 
                bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
                   console.log("more updates" );
                });        
            console.log("done now");
        }
    });
});
```

Once the updates are done you can then do either of the couple of approaches. 
One of them is to use the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator:

```
var voteDate = new Date(2015, 6, 21);
Voter.find({ 
    "$where": "this.votingHistory.length > 8",
    "votingHistory": { "$gt": voteDate  }
}).exec(callback);
```

The other is by using the **[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to "trick" mongodb into looking for documents that have at least a 9th `votingHistory` array element:

```
var voteDate = new Date(2015, 6, 21);
Voter.find({ 
    "votingHistory.8": { "$exists": true },
    "votingHistory": { "$gt": voteDate }
}).exec(callback);
```

For a solution based on the **[`aggregation framework`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec)** (based on the assumptions that the dates are proper MongoDB dates), the following pipeline would give you the desired result:

```
var voteDate = new Date(2015, 6, 21),
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$project": {
                "name": 1, 
                "registrationDate": 1,
                "votingHistory": 1,
                "numberOfVotes": { "$size": "$votingHistory" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "numberOfVotes": { "$gt": 8 },
                "votingHistory": { "$gt": voteDate }
            }
        }

    ];
// you can then use the aggregate   
Voter.aggregate(pipeline)
     .exec(function (err, results){
        // access your results here
     });

// or using the aggregation builder
Voter.aggregate()
    .project({
        "name": 1, 
        "registrationDate": 1,
        "votingHistory": 1,
        "numberOfVotes": { "$size": "$votingHistory" }
    })
    .match({
        "numberOfVotes": { "$gt": 8 },
        "votingHistory": { "$gt": voteDate }
    })
    .exec(callback);
```

Comment: I refactored the dates, but neither of the searches you provided give the desired behavior.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some sample data with the expected result?

Comment: Its has been edited. Thank you for your extensive help. I may manipulate the data so that every election date is its own subdocument. I think I know how to do this if the data is in that format.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you are willing to use mongo agrregation like below

```
db.voter.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$votingHistory"},
{ $match: {votingHistory:{$gt:'2015-7-21T15:41:36+00:00'}}}, 
{$group:{_id: {voterId:'$_id',name:'$name',registrationDate:'$registrationDate'}, count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gt:2}}},
{$project:{_id:"$_id.voterId", name:"$_id.name", registrationDate:"$_id.registrationDate"}}
])
```

Comment: I'll upvote your answer for pointing me in the right direction, though your example code returns a long _pipeline object, which I do not know how to use. If I can figure out how to actually use aggregates to solve my problem I will accept your answer.

Comment: Sure. If I know your expected output I can try helping.

Comment: @SriniKandula The OP is using async node.js and Mongoose but your answer is using the synchronous shell. I assume that's what's tripping him up.

Comment: @JohnnyHK You're correct, I was missing that. Mongo shell and mongoose have such close syntax.

Comment: I had to downvote your answer because I asked specifically for a solution using mongoose. Sorry!